# Make subdivisions of lists in Racket

Tags: list, function, scheme, racket

I want to make a function in Scheme that makes sublists out of a list in a way that I can give a value to start the subdivision and a value to stop it, something like this:

```
(function '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3) 1 3)
>'((1 2 3) (1 4 5 6 3))
```

And I can't find a correct way to do it, as you can see the function would start a sublist with 1 and end it with 3, how can I implement something like this?

Comment: The problem is a bit underspecified — what would happen to values that don't "fit", as with e.g. `(function '(1 2) 1 3)` and `(function '(2 1 3 4 1 3 5) 1 3)`? Are they just dropped?

Comment: You're right, I don't need any specific output for values that don't fit the criteria, an error or returning the same input would be fine.

Comment: How would the result be of `(function '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3 1) 4 5)`?

Comment: That output would be something like this:

'(1 2 3 1 (4 5) 6 3 1)

If you're more comfortable with doing it in a way that the first element in the list has to be the second input (in this case: 4) then be my guest, let's assume everything works the way I stated in the original question.

EDIT: Better yet, make the output just '(4 5).

Comment: Why do you want symbols in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with — there's undoubtedly much more elegant ways of doing it.

The idea is to drop everything until you find the "start" value, then keep everything until the "stop" value (if there is one) and then recurse over the remaining list.

```
#lang racket
(require srfi/1) ; For drop-while

(define (subdiv ls start stop)
  (let ([part-one (drop-while (lambda (x) (not (= x start))) ls)])
    (let-values ([(main rest) (splitf-at part-one (lambda (x) (not (= x stop))))])
      (if (null? rest)         ; empty means the stop value wasn't found
          '()
          (cons (append main (list stop)) 
                (subdiv (cdr rest) start stop))))))
```

Example:

```
> (subdiv '(3 4 5 1 111 1 1 1 2 2 3 1 2) 1 2)
'((1 111 1 1 1 2) (1 2))
> (subdiv '(3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2) 1 2)
'((1 2) (1 2))
> (subdiv '(1 2) 1 2)
'((1 2))
> (subdiv '(1) 1 2)
'()
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is non greedy so it makes the shortest answers (stops at the very first end after it has encountered start) and continues looking for matches after the last end position. It's a roll your own solution without fancy list procedures but it's also tail recursive.

```scm
(define (sublist src start end)
  (let loop ((lst src) (acc #f) (results '()))
    (cond 
      ((null? lst) (reverse results)) ; remove reverse if the order of matches isn't an issue
      ((not acc) (loop (cdr lst) (if (eqv? (car lst) start) (list (car lst)) #f) results))
      ((not (eqv? (car lst) end)) (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc) results))
      (else (loop (cdr lst) #f (cons (reverse (cons (car lst) acc)) results))))))


(sublist '(1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 2) 1 2) ; ==> ((1 2) (1 3 2))
(sublist '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3 1 4 8 7 9 5) 4 5) ; ((4 5) (4 8 7 9 5))
```

For something to find overlapping results this might work:

```scm
(define (sublist-full src start end)
  (let loop ((lst src) (acc #f) (backtrack #f) (results '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        (if backtrack 
            (loop backtrack #f #f results)
            (reverse results))
        (let ((a (car lst)))
          (if acc
              (cond ((and (eqv? a start) (not backtrack)) (loop (cdr lst) (cons a acc) lst results))
                    ((eqv? a end) (loop (cdr lst) (cons a acc) backtrack (cons (reverse (cons a acc)) results)))
                    (else (loop (cdr lst) (cons a acc) backtrack results)))
              (if (eqv? a start)
                  (loop (cdr lst) (cons a '()) #f results)
                  (loop (cdr lst) #f #f results)))))))

(sublist-full '(1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 2) 1 2) 
; ==> ((1 2) (1 2 1 3 2) (1 2 1 3 2 2) (1 2 1 3 2 2 2) 
;      (1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2) (1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 2) (1 3 2) 
;      (1 3 2 2) (1 3 2 2 2) (1 3 2 2 2 2) (1 3 2 2 2 2 2))
```

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I'm getting:
(sublist '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4) ; ==>  (3 4 5)
The other big problem is that I want the output to be all the sublists that match the criteria, for example this is okay:

`(sublist '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3 1) 4 5) ; ==> (4 5)`

But this is wrong:

`(sublist '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3 1 4 8 7 9 5) 4 5) ; ==> (4 5)`

It should be

`(sublist '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3 1 4 8 7 9 5) 4 5) ; ==> '((4 5) (4 8 7 9 5))`

As I said, I really don't care about inputs that don't match the criteria, the last two examples you have are fine by me.

Comment: Are you saying the start and end are not indexes but actual values in the beginning and end of the sublist? Thus `(sublist '(1 2 2 2 2 2) 1 2) ; ==> ((1 2) (1 2 2) (1 2 2 2) (1 2 2 2 2) (1 2 2 2 2 2))`??

Comment: I'm saying exactly that, the case you point out isn't exactly what I'm looking for, I just want to assume that doesn't happen, the list never has two [end of the sublist] values next to each other.

The only case I'm worried about is the one in the original question, I don't mind how it behaves for other kind of combinations.

Though I see how you're concerned, that case would imply something like this too:

`(function '(1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3) 1 3) ; ==> '((1 2 3) (1 2 3 1 4 5 6 3))` Which if you see the orignal question isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for '((1 2 3) (1 4 5 6 3)).